# Gson Não Converte Lista Em Json

Tags: java, json, gson

Toda vez que tento puxar todos os dados de uma tabela do banco e converter o resultado para json, utilizando Gson, dá erro.

```
@GET
@Path("todos")
public String todos() {
    Gson g = new Gson();
    UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository = new UsuarioRepository();
    List<Usuario> usuarios = usuarioRepository.todos();

    String result = g.toJson(usuarios );

    return result;
}
```

Log do erro:

```
29-Mar-2017 10:55:27.383 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-51] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [ReformaTeste] in context with path [/ReformaTeste] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:250)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:235)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(Type
```

Comment: `java.lang.StackOverflowError`: provavelmente há em `Usuario` um atributo de mesmo tipo, sem *back reference* configurado de forma correta. Em resumo, você tem referência cíclica. Atualize com os objetos que estão gerando o erro.

Comment: Como assim @BrunoCésar? Não alterei nada, apenas ficou desse jeito, sem mais nem menos.

Comment: Acabei de verificar, está acontecendo com todas as outras.

Comment: Então dá uma olhada se não mudou nada no classpath, alguma alteração em dados que fez o comportamento aparecer, etc. Sem mais nem menos não existe, é só uma situação que não foi exercitada antes ;) Você pode incluir um [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), com dados de exemplo, para facilitar na simulação do problema, versão das bibliotecas utilizadas - a árvore de dependência do mcve -, etc.

Comment: Não mudei nada. Apenas tentei fazer um teste nesse mesmo método puxando todos os dados da entidade Comodos, deu esse erro. Então voltei tudo com estava, mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Existe relacionamento entre os usuários?